# Why does converting a negative string into a number ( +"-2.333" ) return NaN, only when the string came from d3.format function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3-format's `format` function to round some numbers (yes, I know this isn't necessary).

When I format negative numbers, I get a string of a negative number, as expected. However, when I convert it back into a number using the `+` shorthand, it returns `NaN`. This is not what should happen.  I should get back a regular negative number.

```js
import {format} from "d3-format"; //version 3.1.0

let numberFormatter = d3.format(".3f");
let neg = -2.333;
let negString = "-2.333";
let d3negString = numberFormatter(neg);

//the strings look the same
console.log(d3negString) // "-2.333"
console.log(negString)   // "-2.333"

//both strings have the same type of 'string'
console.log(typeof negString === typeof d3negString); // true

//but they are not equal
console.log(negString === d3negString); // false 

//normal strings work as expected
console.log(isNaN(+negString)); // false

//but strings from d3-format function returns NaN
console.log(isNaN(+d3negString)); // true
```

It says that both strings have the same type 'string', however their values are not equal?? Even though the text is equal?

What is the true type of d3-formatted number strings? They can't just be normal strings, right? Why is it returning NaN? Is this a bug?

```
MacOS Big Sur
Chrome 96.0.4664.110
d3-format@3.1.0
```

Comment: What's the charCodeAt(0), to uniquely identify the first character?

Comment: @jonrsharpe great catch. the negative symbol in a normal string is 45, while from d3-format it is 8722. What a mess.

Answer (score 3):

The change log of d3, shows that in [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/releases/tag/v2.0.0) the following was changed:

> Change the default minus sign to the minus sign (−) instead of hyphen-minus (-).

In [this thread on D3's github](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/issues/62) are some interesting comments:

> D3 did use the minus sign originally, but people complained about that, too (e.g., [#595](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/595)), primarily because there was an expectation that d3.format would use the same symbol as JavaScript’s `number.toString`. The minus sign was thus replaced with [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) in [2.10.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v2.10.0) ([da3131c](https://github.com/d3/d3/commit/da3131c87614b2a9924aa71931e37802eb0efae1), [#756](https://github.com/d3/d3/pull/756)).

And:

> This is now available as an opt-in by specifying the locale’s `minus` property. And I’m considering making the minus sign the default (again) in the next major version.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because the 'minus' characters, despite appearing identical, are different unicode symbols.

Luckily, d3 provides a way to change the default minus character to whatever you choose using the `formatLocale` function.]

['HYPHEN-MINUS'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) U+002D unicode character is recognized as a 'negative sign'.

```
// import {format} from 'd3-format' //do not directly import format with default settings

import { formatLocale} from "d3-format"
const format  = formatLocale({ minus: "\u002D"}).format 

let numberFormatter = d3.format(".3f");
let neg = -2.333;
let negString = "-2.333";
let d3negString = numberFormatter(neg);
console.log(d3negString) // "-2.333"
console.log(negString)   // "-2.333"
console.log(typeof negString === typeof d3negString); // true
console.log(negString === d3negString); // true 
console.log(isNaN(+negString)); // false
console.log(isNaN(+d3negString)); // false
```

The larger moral of the story is that d3-format's goal is NOT to round numbers - it is to make number look nice *as text*. To prevent problems, use `Math.round()` or `"-2.3333".toFixed(3) // => -2.333` to round numbers in javascript.